# How to hide div when array length is 0

Tags: angular, typescript

I have table of objects (Bills => Bill => Products => Product). Each of them contains another table which filters using pipe. Pipe filtering works fine but after filtering the arrays their names (`bill.name`) are still visible even though they don't show any result of filtering. How can I solve this problem?

```
<span class="search-span">
    <input [(ngModel)]="searchText" placeholder="Start typing a product name..." class="search-input">
</span>
</div>
<hr>
<ng-container *ngFor="let bill of bills; let i = index">
    <div class="col-xs-12" *ngIf="bill.products?.length > 0">
        <h5>
            {{bill.name}} {{i === 0 ? '(this bill group)' : ''}}
        </h5>
    </div>          
    <div class="col-xs-3" *ngFor="let product of bill.products | filter : searchText">
        <div [class.selected]="isProductSelected(product)" (click)="selectProduct(product)">
            <span class="text">{{product.name}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

Pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(items: any, searchText: string): any {
    if (!items) return [];

    if (!searchText) return items;

    searchText = searchText.toLowerCase();

    return items.filter(it => {
      return it.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchText);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the declaration of the filtered products to a `<ng-container>`

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let bill of bills; let i = index">
    <ng-container *ngIf="(bill.products | filter : searchText) as filtered">
       <ng-container *ngIf="filtered.length else noProducts">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
              <h5>
                  {{bill.name}} {{i === 0 ? '(this bill group)' : ''}}
              </h5>
          </div>          
          <div class="col-xs-3" *ngFor="let product of filtered">
              <div [class.selected]="isProductSelected(product)" (click)="selectProduct(product)">
                  <span class="text">{{product.name}}</span>
              </div>
          </div>
       </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
</ng-container>
<ng-template #noProducts>
   <span>No Products Found</span>
</ng-template>
```

You can nest multiple `<ng-container>` and you can use the `*ngIf="XXX as YYY"` syntax to apply a condition and store the result in a new template variable.

Comment: how add information " no products found", when i make ngif with !filtered?.length it shows always when array is empty, i want only one information.

Comment: could you help me ?

Comment: @aKa I'm sorry. I don't understand. When do you want to show the "no products found" message? When there is only one product?

Comment: i want to show supporting information "No product found" when filtering returns 0 elements.

Comment: @aka Okay. I updated the answer. You can use the `*ngIf="filtered.length else noProducts"` syntax to render a template.

Comment: unfortunately, but still when filtering does not return any product, it shows: no product found
no product found
no product found
no product found
no product found
no product found
no product found
no product found